# PayPal Sandbox Login

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I login to my PayPal developer account through: `developer.paypal.com`, where I have various test accounts set up.  Then, I navigate to `sandbox.paypal.com`, but the site displays a message saying: "**Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features.**"

**This used to work couple of months ago; what has changed?  Am I missing a step?**

Comment: Same here; had it for 48 hours. Also posted on the pp forums: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-sandbox/unable-set-ipn-sandbox-unable-open-profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used opera and remove every private data such as cookies, cache, session cookies... and it is working.
I suppose that it is going to work in other browsers also

Comment: Downloaded and installed opera; doesn't solve it here.

Comment: I used Firefox and done the same thing and it works, also I tried using Google Chrome incognito(CTRL+SHIFT+N)  and it works

Answer (score 2):

The error:

"Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features."

While logging into the Sandbox account or navigating through the account is a known issue we're working to resolve now. Sorry everyone for the impact it's caused however I'll be sure to update this post once it's been fixed.

If you're experiencing another issue within developer or sandbox please feel free to comment with the issue you're experiencing and I'll be sure to look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

Existing Sandbox users
All U.S. and non U.S. developers must log in with a PayPal account to use Sandbox. Once you log in, use your existing PayPal Developer Central username and password to import Sandbox test accounts. See our FAQ.

Comment: Yes, I have logged in to developer central, imported my old sandbox test accounts, created new ones, etc.  Then, while still logged in, I navigate to sandbox.paypal.com, but get a "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features" message rather than the usual login form for test accounts.

Comment: It happens to me aswell and it is annoying

Comment: I used opera and remove every private data such as cookies, cache... and it is working

Comment: Yes, it has something to do with old paypal cookies

Comment: FosAvance, go ahead and submit an answer and I'll select it as the solution.  thanks!